# make text bold in the middle of the sentence

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How can I make a single word bold from the whole sentence?

```
Hello my name is stackoverflow
```

If i try to use `<b> stackoverflow </b>`

The word goes to the next line. What else can I try?

```html
<span>Hello my name is <b> stackoverflow </b></span>

<div>Hello my name is <b> stackoverflow </b></div>

<p>Hello my name is <b> stackoverflow </b></p>

Hello my name is <b> stackoverflow </b>
```

Edit:

```
    <main className='content'>
    <img src={poly} alt="charts" className="charts" />
    <div className="heading">
    What's the topic?
    </div>
    This is called <strong>underfitting</strong>underfitting. A polynomial of degree 4 approximates 
      <div className="popup">
  <Popup/> 
  </div >
  <div className="regressionSetup">
    <RegressionItemsContainer/>
    </div>
      </main>
```

```
.content{
    padding-left: 260px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: white;
}

.popup{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.charts{
    align-self: center;
    height: 350px;
    width: 800px;
}

.heading{
    font-size: 25px;

}
```

Even with the < strong > tag, the bold word goes to the next line. I have added the remaining css code for the page. What could be the issue?
[image]

Comment: you can use font-weight in your css, but you would have to wrap the word you want to make bold in a span with a class or id. There's no guarantee it wouldn't go onto the next line though. You could reduce font size or adjust kerning or increase width

Comment: `<b>` doesn't necessarily mean the text will be bold https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b

Comment: Can you show an example of the `<b>` tag making text go to the next line? Your error is most probably somewhere else in the code if that is happening.

Comment: Try the snippet above. What doesn't work there? Please show us an example of your code so we can try and reproduce here.

Comment: @Ivan86 with <span> it works, otherwise it was going to the next line as shown in the qs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your bold text is going to a new line because the main container, `.content`, is `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` which will put every new group under the previous.

To prevent the bold text going to the next line, put the whole sentence into its own tag of some sort such as a span.

`<span>This is called <strong>underfitting</strong>. A polynomial of degree 4 approximates</span>`

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the `<strong>` tag or surround the word you want to bold with `<span class='bold'>` and in the css set:

```
.bold {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: `strong` adds semantics that may not be intended. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong

Comment: It does, but it is also the new and preferred way. Also semantics don't have downsides. Essentially does the same thing with a benefit.

Comment: that's a "it depends" topic right there, but I do agree that: semantics > no semantics